# Get infromation from Google Tag Manager account interface

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to use Google Tag Manager(GTM) to collect some information when a visitor submits a form.

I've set this little code on my page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dataLayer = [{
        'productSku': 'pbz00123',
        'productName': 'The Original Rider Waite Tarot cards',
        'productPrice': '9.99'
    }];
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'test'
    });
</script>
```

The variables and event are set into my GTM account interface but now I want to know how to get that information?

I can't get that information in Google Analytics or any other Google tool.

Comment: You'll need to create a tag that will fire with the trigger based on your event "test", that exposes those product details through, for example, custom dimensions.

Comment: Ok @nyuen and then, after that, on which page can we get those collected datas ?

Comment: You can get them on almost any page as secondary dimensions, for example in the ecommerce product pages. Or you can create custom reports to show them all.